# Passing in an object as an out parameter

Tags: c#, reference

I have a method that checks for validity of an object with respect to my program (some algorithm). The object is created(parsed) from a string that is passed in.

The logic is:

```
 bool isValid(String str, out Object obj)
    {
         obj = null;
         obj = new Object(str); //Validation happens during the object creating
         if(obj.Legit) //Don't mind this line :)
             return true;
         return false;
    }
```

And I call this validation from another class, which if this validation fails, does a different validation (same method)

```
void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
        if(isValid(str, out ??????)
             //process
}
```

So instead of ?????, I don't know how to pass the object.

I have only 1 constructor, Object(String).

Comment: Nice catch =) Editted.

Comment: Note that this is not a proper name. `isValid` suggests a test/check method but it also creates something. Call it `TryParse` instead.

Comment: @HenkHolterman don't go pulling _that_ thread...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This MSDN document describes the "out" keyword:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

Before you call the isValid() method, you need to declare the output object:

```
void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
    Object obj;
    if(isValid(str, out obj)
         //process
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to declare it inside the parameter? Or is that the only way?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that. C# is a language that requires declaration before assignment.

Comment: As of C# 7 (2017) you can declare out parameters inline. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

As nic said, typically you would say:

```
void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
    object obj;
    if(isValid(str, out obj)
    {
         // process valid obj
    }
}
```

That's perfectly acceptable. However, there are other ways you could do this that are possibly better:

```
Thing GetThing(String str)
{
     Thing thing = new Thing(str);
     if(thing.Legit)
         return thing;
     return null;
}

void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
    Thing thing = GetThing();
    if(thing != null)
         //process
}
```

Here's another:

```
Thing GetThing(String str)
{
     // Make a static method that tests the string.
     if (Thing.IsLegit(str)) 
         return new Thing(str);
     return null;
}

void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
    Thing thing = GetThing();
    if(thing != null)
         //process
}
```

Of course if you are going to do that then why do you need GetThing?  Just say:

```
void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
     if (Thing.IsLegit(str)) 
     {
         Thing thing = new Thing(str);
         //process
     }
}
```

This last pattern is probably the best. You want to **separate your concerns**. When you have an `out` parameter it is usually because *the method is trying to do too many things*.

Comment: Your point seems clear, but out of curiosity, are you not a "TryParse" kind of guy?

Comment: Another option is just to call a constructor and catch exceptions that it throws.

Comment: @nic: Then you have to ask the question as to whether the exception is truly *exceptional*. If it is unexceptional then don't make the caller handle an exception; always give the caller a way to avoid the exception.

Comment: @TimLehner: I dearly wish that `int.TryParse` returned an `int?` rather than a bool and an out parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to declare an object. The below code will work for you.

```
void FindingObjectType(String str)
{
        Object obj;
        if(isValid(str, out obj)
             //process
}
```

Comment: The code will work but does not create an _instance_. It only declares a reference variable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the instance is created inside the IsValid method.

Comment: Though the instance is created inside isValid method, ypdated the text to clear the confusion.